# Wrong timestamp in syslog

Tags: security, syslog, timestamp

I was taking a look on my syslog, and I found this:

```
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[963]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2580
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::fef8:aeff:fe3d:f9b9 on wlan0.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::fef8:aeff:fe3d:f9b9.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari kernel: [ 1655.564005] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:07:7d:d2:3f:20 by local choice (reason=3)
Nov 30 22:28:36 nori-hidamari wpa_supplicant[1056]: message repeated 14 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari wpa_supplicant[1056]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:07:7d:d2:3f:20 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Withdrawing address record for 172.26.224.61 on wlan0.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 172.26.224.61.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari avahi-daemon[645]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[963]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari NetworkManager[963]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 30 22:30:01 nori-hidamari dnsmasq[2600]: setting upstream servers from DBus
```

So, looks like one timestamp is strange. Should I worry about that?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the fact that the message is repeated x number of times. You will see the time stamp of the first message, which apparently is repeated 14 times with 6 seconds in between, thus showing up 84 seconds (and a bit) later in the log.
Generally, if you look at the output of `grep -a3 -b3 repeated /var/log/syslog` you will see that the repeated message has a different time stamp from those before and after.

Comment: So, you are telling me that those messages started at 22:28:36, so that's why it appeared later in the logs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The timestamp given is the timestamp of the first message. BTW [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1323089) gives a good description of why this message appears, and how you can make it go away.